# Override EntityResponse toString method

Tags: java, rest, swagger, tostring

I am playing around with REST service.
I have created with swagger editor an API definition and then I have generated the code for a Springboot server.
After some changes in Eclipse, all works fine, but I have one "problem", I am not able to override the toString method to display the result as I want.
(there is an object called Genre with genreId and definition, I don't want to display the genreId)

This is the method implementation in Controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> findMovies(
@ApiParam(value = "Tags used to filter the result") @RequestParam(value = 
"tags", required = false) List<String> tags,
@ApiParam(value = "maximum number of results to return") @RequestParam(value = 
"limit", required = false) Integer limit) {
List<Movie> movies = movieRepository.findAll();
return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(movies, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This is the toString method in Model class:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
return "Movie {"+"movieId='" + movieId + '\'' + ", title='" + title + '\'' +", 
description='"+ description + '\'' +", rating='"+rating+ '\'' 
+"price='"+price+ '\'' +"genres='"+genres+  '}';
}
```

Genres is a list of object Genre that have genreId and definition. 
I have also this in Genre class:

```
@Id
@JsonProperty("genre_id")
@JsonIgnore
private String genreId;
private String definition;
```

this is the toString method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Genre {"+"definition='" + definition + '}';
}
```

I don't want to have genreId in my results, but I have it. 
Debugging the code I saw that in controller:
return new ResponseEntity>(movies, HttpStatus.OK);
the movie object does't have the genreId, so for some
reasons ResponseEntity print it. I have inserte a brekpoint and the toString method inside Genre is not called

this is an example of result:

```
{
"genres": [
{
"genreId": "1",
"definition": "Fantasy"
}
],
"movie_id": "2",
"title": "The Hobbit",
"description": "A fantasy journey",
"rating": 6,
"price": 30
}
```

Some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is generated by JSON serializer, it does not use `toString()` method.

It uses field annotations to determine which fields should be serialized (or ignored) to json-format. Mark `genreId` in your `Genre` class with `@JsonIgnore` annotation to exclude this field from JSON output.

**Update**
In some cases (based on JSON serializer configuration/bugs/etc, it is not enough to mark the field with `@JsonIgonre`, you should also mark the getter of this field too. As it is shown below.

Example:

```
class Genre {

   @JsonIgnore
   private long genreId;

   @JsonIgnore
   public long getGenreId() { 
      return genreId;
   }
   // the rest of your Genre class ... 
}
```

Comment: That is wath I have in my code:  -@Id
 -@JsonProperty("genre_id")
 -@JsonIgnore
 private String genreId;
 private String definition;